# openssl s_client set character mode

Tags: openssl

I am porting my telnet IM server to support SSL connections, and I test it with the command "openssl s_client -connect IP" on Linux, which connects to the server without errors. However, on telnet I was able to set the character mode (LINEMODE option) so that every character is sent right when you press the key and not enter, without any buffering.

How do I set this behaviour in the openssl client? I can't find any option that does it. Is there an alternative to the command that does allow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are out of luck with `s_client`. You should try `socat` which is an order of magnitude more powerful:

```
socat stdin,icanon=0 ssl:IP:PORT
```

See also [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/346958/669855).

Comment: `socat` prints `E SSL_connect(): error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`. The certificate is self-signed and was working on `s_client`.

Comment: Then ask `socat` to not verify it: `socat stdin,icanon=0 ssl:IP:PORT,verify=0`